# Asymptote out-of-memory error when plotting many points

Tags: asymptote, memory

I am using `Asymptote 2.37` on Windows 7.  I'm trying to make some large scatter plots but get a memory error.  When trying to process the following MWE

```
unitsize(10inch);
for (int i = 0; i < 140000; ++i)
{
    dot((unitrand(), unitrand()));
}
```

I get the error

> error: out of memory

and no output image.  Drawing 130,000 dots works, producing a 1.4Mb PDF in just a few seconds.

I don't believe the error is caused by any hardware limitation.  I have 29Gb RAM available and plenty of hard drive space.

Is this an `Asymptote` bug or just a known limitation?

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with Asymptote on a Windows machine. The Windows version of Asymptote seems to be the problem as the out-of-memory error messages disappeared when I ran my code on a Linux machine.

Comment: This probably qualifies as a "known limitation." I'm guessing there's a setting somewhere when the binary is compiled that tells it the max amount of RAM the binary is allowed to use. If feasible, you might try recompiling Asymptote from source; on a mac the git instructions are the easiest to follow, but I don't know how that would work on a Windows machine. (Maybe with cygwin?)

Comment: You could try the option `-compact` of `asy`. For me it solved the problem.